# Clearing certain data from column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a [`pandas.Dataframe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) where after processing it looks like this:

```
Type|Fiscal quarter
A|FY18 Q3
A|FY18 Q4
A|FYn Q3
```

I would like to clear data where date = FYn type

So it will look like this:

```
Type|Fiscal quarter
A|FY18 Q3
A|FY18 Q4
A|
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas offers `pd.replace`, so you can use:

```
df['Fiscal quarter']=df['Fiscal quarter'].replace('FYn.*','',regex=True)
```

This will achieve the desired purpose using the regex `FYn.*`

Answer (score 1):

You can test the value of the `Fiscal quarter` column and use it to select the values to replace like:

#### Code:

```
df['Fiscal quarter'][df['Fiscal quarter'].str.startswith('FYn')] = ''
```

### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ('A', 'FY18 Q3'),
    ('A', 'FY18 Q4'),
    ('A', 'FYn Q3'),
], columns=['Type', 'Fiscal quarter'])

print(df)

df['Fiscal quarter'][df['Fiscal quarter'].str.startswith('FYn')] = ''
print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
  Type Fiscal quarter
0    A        FY18 Q3
1    A        FY18 Q4
2    A         FYn Q3

  Type Fiscal quarter
0    A        FY18 Q3
1    A        FY18 Q4
2    A
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use easily understandable `for` loop to check and change each row:

```
import pandas as pd
newvals = []                          # create new list for new dataframe
for v in df.values:                   # v will be as: ['A' 'FY18 Q3']
    if v[1].startswith("FYn"):        # remove entry if criteria satisfied
        v[1] = ""
    newvals.append(v)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=newvals, columns=df.columns)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Type Fiscal quarter
0    A        FY18 Q3
1    A        FY18 Q4
2    A
```